# C++ Int returns different value than double for same input in Atom

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I'm doing algorithm for solving Quadratic equation.

I type for A = 4, B = 10, C = 4 which gives value of 36 for delta.

My issue is that

```
int delta;
```

returns value of 35, and

```
double delta;
```

returns value of 36.

I'm using Atom text editor, rest of code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  int delta;
  int x1, x2;
  cout << "Rownanie kwadratowe w postaci ax^2 + bx + c = 0" << endl;
  cout << "Podaj wartosc A" << endl;
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Podaj wartosc B" << endl;
  cin >> b;
  cout << "Podaj wartosc C" << endl;
  cin >> c;
  delta = pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);
  cout << "Delta = " << delta << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417a9fe9f554d09b) but possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `int` -> `double`

Comment: Probably a rounding error. Try `delta = (pow(b,2)+0.5) - (4 * a * c);` Or even better, `delta = b*b - 4 *a * c`

Comment: It's a rounding error, why not just use `double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Bellow code is much shorter and better for the Minimum example, isn't it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 4, b = 10, c = 4;
  int delta = pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);
  cout << "Delta = " << delta << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If you use integral arithmetic then use integral not floating point operations. The problem consists of floats. Result of `pow(b, 2)` may be like `99.99999999997`, that rounded down to int is `99`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 4, b = 10, c = 4;
  int delta = b * b - (4 * a * c);
  cout << "Delta = " << delta << endl;
  return 0;
}
```